# Complex View shows wrong value for table

Tags: sql, oracle12c

We have a funny behaviour in one of our dev dbs.

It startet with someone building a new view and comparing it with an old one, with a statement like

```
select * from old_view where id=1234
union
select * from new_view where id=1234;
```

It showed a difference for one value, but if you execute them seperatly, they show the same values.
So, I looked into the old_view, it looks like this:

```
select some_function() as a,
some_value as b,
to_char(some_date, 'YYYYMMDD') as c,
DECODE (funny_table.funny_field, 0, '01', '12') AS D, --that's the funny value
null as e,
some_value as f
from some_view a
          LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table 
             ON something
          LEFT OUTER JOIN funny_table ON something
          LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table ON something;
```

Now, where it get's strange again. If I execute this, with the id in the where-clause, it works fine. If I add `funny_table.funny_field` at the end of the select-part, it shows the wrong value(0 instead of 1) and the decode also shows the wrong value.
When I select the funny_table, it also seems fine.

I tried

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;

ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE;
```

which didn't change anything and `DBMS_REPAIR.CHECK_OBJECT` also doesn't show anything wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it's because of `LEFT JOIN  funny_table ON something`. Your join produces `NULL` in your `funny_field`.

Comment: No, it does not produce null. It produces 0 instead of 1(but just this one field that matters, when I use `funny_table.*`, all the other columns are right). But funnily, when I use an inner join it seems to work. But that is not an option.
If I select another field from `funny_table` than `funny_field` (without selecting `funny_field`) it also works.